# Installation issues in hadoop,hbase,zookerper in single node in debian

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to install hadoop,habse,zookeeper in my local machine. But i am facing problem in zookeeper connection.

Below is the hbase master log:

```
2013-07-21 22:01:24,603 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2013-07-21 22:01:24,603 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2013-07-21 22:01:24,603 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2013-07-21 22:01:24,603 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2013-07-21 22:01:24,603 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.2.0-4-amd64
2013-07-21 22:01:24,603 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=gaurav
2013-07-21 22:01:24,604 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/gaurav
2013-07-21 22:01:24,604 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1/bin
2013-07-21 22:01:24,605 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=master:60000
2013-07-21 22:01:24,636 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2013-07-21 22:01:24,637 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 22559@gaurav
2013-07-21 22:01:24,643 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:708)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

i configure hadoop from this link
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/?

hbase configuration hbase-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright 2010 The Apache Software Foundation
 *
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
-->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
<description>The directory shared by RegionServers</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>localhost</value>
<description>Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.
For example,
"host1.mydomain.com,host2.mydomain.com,host3.mydomain.com".
By default this is set to localhost for local and pseudo-distributed modes of operation. For a fully-distributed setup, this should be set to a full list of ZooKeeper quorum servers. If HBASE_MANAGES_ZK is set in hbase-env.shthis is the list of servers which we will start/stop ZooKeeper on.
</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.master.port</name>
<value>60000</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2222</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/hbase/zookeeper</value>
</property>
 <property>
<name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
<value>/home/hbase/hbase-0.94.6.1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
<value>1000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hbase-env.sh

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_25
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
only this are set in this file

and i have only two folder hadoop and hbase , one for hadoop package and there for hbase package

hbase master log 
http://pastebin.com/TUvx4BgX?

Answer (score 0):

Your hbase master is not starting properly,that is why it is unable to connect to 60000 port.Check the following in your hadoop and hbase conf.

1. In the hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml.check the value of the hbase.master property.it should be 60000.
2. check if the port in the hbase conf is properly configured with the hadoop port.
3. check if the zookeeper conf is having the same port of hbase master.

Also do netstat and check whether hadoop and hbase port are available.

If you can attach the conf file,i would able to give you more details

Comment: i dont know. if i need to install zookeeper separate . i just configure hbase-site.xml in hbase and hadoop configure in core-site.xml, is it enough for starting zookeeper or i need to install zookeeper separately

Comment: please check the new updated question i have attached conf file and log for hbase.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, You dont have to install zookeeper separately.in the link you specified  http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/, port 54310 is used for fs.default.name.but in your hbase conf it is 9000.please make sure that these two ports are same. Also in the above config hbase.zookeeper.quorum property is defined twice and dfs.replication is not required.

Comment: i am able to configure all things .. and all running fine . i will give the link to a blogs .. where i tell what problems i face and what was the solution.